Unix domain socket frame structure
How does a unix domain socket packet look like? Is it like a TCP/IP packet which have an ethernet header, an IP header and a TCP header? How do they look like in unix domain socket?

Unix domain sockets are not transmitted over the wire, they only exist inside the one machine. So they don't have a packet header in that sense.
AFAIK stream oriented unix domain sockets (SOCK_STREAM) are not even broken into packets as such.  Message oriented sockets (SOCK_DGRAM) may have a data structure associated with each message although this will be entirely internal to the Kernel.

Thanks for the reply, any source code reference is appreciated.
